# Visualizing Lie algebra of SO(3)

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras, visualization

Let $SO(3)$ be the Lie group of 3D rotations. 
Rotation about z-axis by an angle $\phi$ is represented in standard basis by this matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos \phi & -\sin\phi & 0 \\
  \sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Differentiating this matrix at $\phi = 0$ we get an infinitesimal generator of rotation about z-axis:
$$
Z = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$$

In similar fashion we get matrices $X$ and $Y$ corresponding to rotations about x- and y-axis.
These matrices are elements of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ and bracketing gives us:

$$[X, Y] = -Z, [Y, Z] = -X, [Z, X] = -Y$$

I'm not really good at visualizing things, but I'm curious is there a nice visual explanation for this?

Comment: i think it's the ordinary cross product on $\mathbb R^3,$ perhaps $-1$ times the usual cross product.

Comment: Right, if you switch your basis to $-X, -Y, -Z,$ you get the cross product.

Comment: [This](http://visuallietheory.blogspot.de/2012/07/infinitesimal-rotations.html) blog post shows my attempt to visualize the Lie algebra so(3).

Comment: @user71769 Thank you, that looks great.

Answer (score 2):

$[X,Y]$ refers to the rate of change of $Y$ over $X$. So it is equal to $Z$. It appears to be the cross product, as @Will Jagy said. If you want a more sophicated explanation of the whole thing, I will have to start over and take some time.

Comment: Let's imagine you are seeing those notions in my post for the first time. Could one with good visual intuition guess $[X, Y]$ proportional to $Z$ before calculating? If I understand correctly, when you say that Lie bracket refers to the rate of change, you think about the Lie bracket of left-invariant vector fields generated by $X, Y, Z$, right? It's not really obvious to me that $[X,Y]$ should be proportional to $Z$ when I think that way. Is it to you? Could you explain how?

Comment: @ante.ceperic Rotate $Y$ about $X$ a very small angle, say $\theta$, and the difference $e^{X\theta}Y-Y$ is almost parallel to $Z$ right? You take the limit of $\lim_{\theta\to 0}(e^{X\theta}Y-Y)/\theta$, and it should be $Z$ right? I abused the notation a little bit, sorry.