# $(\mathbb{R}^{3},\times)$ is a Lie algebra that does not have Lie subalgebras of dimension 2.

Tags: lie-algebras

Could anyone give me a suggestion to start solving this problem?

Proof that $(\mathbb{R}^{3},\times)$ is a Lie algebra that does not have Lie subalgebras of dimension 2.

Comment: addendum: $\times$ denotes the usual cross product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find a basis $(x,y,z)$ for the cross product algebra, which is the $3$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, e.g.,
with brackets
$$
[x,y]=z,\; [y,z]=x,\; [z,x]=y,
$$
see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914269/visualizing-lie-algebra-of-so3). Now it is obvious that there is no $2$-dimensional subalgebra - see also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198401/2-dimensional-lie-subgroups-of-so3/2198429).

Answer (score 4):

Given any two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, their cross product will be perpendicular to the plane that they generate. In particular, no $2$-dimensional subspace can be closed under the Lie bracket.